# Composition over inheritance, sure, but do we have any syntactic sugar for the function passthrough boilerplate?

Tags: rust, encapsulation

If I have a struct implementing a trait, and then I encapsulate that struct in another struct, is there an easy way to pass through all the function calls to implement that trait for the second struct?

```
trait HasAnX {
    fn get_x(&self) -> i32;
}

struct StructA {
    x: i32
}

impl HasAnX for StructA {
    fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
        self.x 
    }
}

struct StructB {
    a: StructA
}

// This is the part I don't want to have to write out for every function in StructA
impl HasAnX for StructB {
    fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
        self.a.get_x() 
    }
}
```

I think half of the problem is that I'm not even sure what this problem is called.

Comment: https://docs.rs/delegate/latest/delegate/, have a nice read https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2393

Answer (score 4):

The need to implement `HasAnX` for `StructB` usually comes from looking at the problem with inheritance in mind.
To avoid this situation try to work with only the part you really care for.

If you just want to call a method on `a` you can do so from the outside:

```rust
struct_b.a.get_x();
```

If you want to work with anything like a `StructA` you can just implement `AsRef<StructA>` for it, similarly you can use `AsMut` for mutable access.
Then functions can just take an `impl AsRef<StructA>` and don't need to care what actual type it is, with the added benefit that it now also can take owned types and references.

```rust
impl AsRef<StructA> for StructB {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &StructA {
        &self.a
    }
}

// you can pass in any of `StructA`, `&StructA`, `StructB`, `&StructB`
pub fn reads_from_a(a: impl AsRef<StructA>) {
    let a = a.as_ref();
    println!("{}", a.get_x());
}
```

If your `StructB` is a sort of smart pointer you can implement `Deref` and just use `StructA`s methods directly on `StructB`

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
impl Deref for StructB {
    type Target = StructA;
    fn deref(&self) -> &StructA {
        &self.a
    }
}

//...

struct_b.get_x();
```

Comment: My use-case is less "smart pointer", and more "car that is also a boat".  "Well what can it do?"  "Everything a boat can do, and everything a car can do.  I'm not going over all that again."

Comment: "Car that is also a boat" is not technical enough to actually answer the question. What is the actual use case? I am kind of convinced OOP people use these made-up real world examples because they're techniques don't work in actual programming problems. In any case, I suspect that just like in real life, you shouldn't have a car that is also a boat. You should have a car and a boat.